# RuntimeException when I try to get an Object Extra from the Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I need to pass a custom Parcelable object to another activity as Extra

I put the extra with this code

```
Car myCarObject=getCar();
ArrayList<Car> parcelableExtra = new ArrayList<Car>();
                parcelableExtra.add(myCarObject);

Intent details = new Intent(Start.this, DetailsCar.class);
                details.putExtra("Car", parcelableExtra);
                startActivity(details);
```

I try to load the extra with this code in the destination Intent

```
ArrayList<Car> parcelableExtra = new ArrayList<Car>();
        parcelableExtra = (ArrayList<Car>) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("Car");
        Car c=parcelableExtra.get(0);
```

But the app crashes with this error stack:

```
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.app.com/my.app.com.DetailsCar}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@4051ac20: Unmarshalling unknown type code 5505097 at offset 3144
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@4051ac20: Unmarshalling unknown type code 5505097 at offset 3144
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1913)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2092)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1536)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at my.app.com.obj.Car.<init>(Car.java:361)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at my.app.com.obj.Car.<init>(Car.java:347)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at my.app.com.obj.Car$1.createFromParcel(Car.java:339)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at my.app.com.obj.Car$1.createFromParcel(Car.java:1)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:1981)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1846)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2092)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1536)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1867)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2083)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:208)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1100)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at my.app.com.DetailsCar.onCreate(DetailsCar.java:43)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
12-14 03:34:24.059: E/AndroidRuntime(16872):    ... 11 more
```

My Parcelable Car Object is this

```
public class Car implements Serializable, Parcelable {
    String description;
    String speed;
    String brake;
    String pro;

    public Car(String description, String speed, String brake,
            String pro) {
        super();
        this.description = description;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.brake = brake;
        this.pro = pro;
    }

    public Car() {

    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel arg0, int arg1) {
        arg0.writeString(description);
        arg0.writeString(speed);
        arg0.writeString(brake);
        arg0.writeString(pro);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Car> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Car>() {
        public Car createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Car(in);
        }

        public Car[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Car[size];
        }
    };

    private Car(Parcel in) {
        description = in.readString();
        speed = in.readString();
        brake = in.readString();
        pro = in.readString();
        in.readArrayList(String.class.getClassLoader());
    }

}
```

How could  I fix this issue?
Any suggestion?

Comment: What line of code does `at my.app.com.obj.Car.<init>(Car.java:361)` correspond to?

Comment: Correspond to in.readArrayList(String.class.getClassLoader()); in the Car object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at two key functions:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel arg0, int arg1) {
    arg0.writeString(description);
    arg0.writeString(speed);
    arg0.writeString(brake);
    arg0.writeString(pro);
}


private Car(Parcel in) {
    description = in.readString();
    speed = in.readString();
    brake = in.readString();
    pro = in.readString();
    in.readArrayList(String.class.getClassLoader());
}
```

Note that the first writes 4 variables to the `Parcel`, and the later reads 5. The system is crashing because there isn't an ArrayList in the Parcel. Put an arrayList in, and you should be fine. Alternatively, you could just remove the read function, as it doesn't even appear to be used (But I will allow for the possibility that more could be in your function than you included)

Comment: What arraylist? I must put the ArrayList in the entire object class? Could you give me a sample? thanks

Comment: If you aren't using an ArrayList, then just remove the last line. It's trying to read something that isn't there... Only keep the line if you intend to save an Array of Strings, otherwise it will only cause you grief.

Comment: If I simply remove the last line get another runtime exception with a null pointer exception

Comment: I have updated the question with more details about the error that happens If I follow your suggestion.

Comment: This has to do with the fact that you are placing an array list of Cars into an Intent, and not reading it out properly. Do you actually need to do this?

Comment: If I don't place the car in an Array list I get a compilation error the method putextra(string parcelable) is ambiguous for the type intent